# popup window insert query not working or data not submitted in database

Tags: php

visit the [link](http://demo11.rslpvtltd.com)

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
  $emailId = $_POST['emailId'];
  $contactNumber = $_POST['contactNumber'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  print_r("INSERT INTO register(full_name,email_id,contact_number,password)values('$fullName','$emailId','$contactNumber','$password')");
  die();

  $insertEnquiry = "INSERT INTO register(full_name,email_id,contact_number,password)values('$fullName','$emailId','$contactNumber','$password')";
  $result = mysql_query($insertEnquiry);
  if ($result) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Login Successfull")';
    echo '</script>';
  } else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Cant submit this form")';
    echo '</script>';
  }
}
?>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!--<div style="text-align:center;"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" style="padding-bottom:10px;"></div>-->
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="javascript:login('hide');"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button></a>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Register Yourself</h4>
      </div>
      <form name="register" action="" method="post">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p style="text-align:center;font-size:20px;">Registration</p>
          <div><input type="text"  name="fullName" class="txtnm"  placeholder="Full Name"></div>
          <input type="text"  name="emailId" class="txtnm"  placeholder="Email-Id">
          <input type="text"  name="contactNumber" class="txtnm"  placeholder="Contact Number">
          <input type="password"  name="password" class="txtnm"  placeholder="Choose Password">
          <!-- <div class="checkbox">
           <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Be the first one to know about new courses and great offers!</label>
          </div>-->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="javascript:login('show');"> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"value="Register"></a>
          </div>
          <div  style="text-align: center;">
            <a class="cancel-link" style="color: black; font-size:12px;">By signing up, you agree to our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy.
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>         <!--modal-body-->
      <div class="modal-foot">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Already have an account? Login</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in this code i have tried data post in database but popup window page not refreshing thatch why my data not submitted in database 
i have doing normal code using php and MySQL
can anyone solve this problem please help me

Comment: i have just check your code from http://demo11.rslpvtltd.com/ link i found that <form> tag is missing in above of  <div class="modal-body"> and also input type is button not submit

Comment: i use <form></form> tag and also change the <input type="submit"> but data not send  in database